# Application Insights Alert webhook data different from documention

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-application-insights

The schema documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-webhooks-alerts#payload-schema is different from what we are seeing after setting up alerts. Our message is not wrapped in a RequestBody -field and we also see a failureDetails field.

Is there some versioning here or what is the reason for the discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

The payload for availability alerts (alerts based on webtests) is slightly different than that of metric-based alerts, which is what is shown in the documentation link you provided.

Comment: Ok. Do you know if that format is described somewhere?